# Sphinx: different ToC anchor names than in generated HTML (Single page)

Tags: html, themes, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I create some documentation with Sphinx using the `singlehtml` builder. When using the `basic` theme no table of contents is included.
So I created a custom theme including the toc:

```
<h1 id="h-title">{{ title|striptags|e }}{{ titlesuffix }}</h1>

<div id="manual-toc">
    <h2 id="h-toc">{{ _('Table of contents') }}</h2>
    {% set toctree = toctree(maxdepth=10, collapse=theme_collapse_navigation, includehidden=True) %}
    {{ toctree }}
</div>

{% block body %}{% endblock %}
```

Using this theme, a single page html with a toc is generated.
Unfortunately the links within the toc are wrong.
Assuming I have the following rst files with some sections:

```
- 01_intro.rst
|- section1
|- section2
- 02_basics.rst
|- section1
|- section2
```

The following anchor links are within the toc and html - you can clearly see that they do not match so clicking a section in the toc results in nothing (but should jump to the appropriate anchor):

```
SECTION        TOC-ANCHOR-LINK                ANCHOR-NAME-IN-HTML
- 01_intro     #document-01_intro             #intro
|- section1    #document-01_intro#section1    #section1
|- section2    #document-01_intro#section1    #section2
- 02_basics    #document-02_basics            #basics
|- section3    #document-02_basics#section3   #section3
|- section4    #document-02_basics#section4   #section4
```

If I don't use `collapse=theme_collapse_navigation` in the template it will only output the top level sections but with correct anchor linking.

What can I do to solve the issue? Thanks in advance!